# How to add all the lines in one go

Tags: c#

So I have this piece of code to add items from a text file into a combobox for an assignment. How would I go about adding all of the items in the text file altogether instead of one by one like I'm doing now.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextReader tr;

    try
    {
        cboCity.Items.Clear();
        tr = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\Alexander\\Desktop\\CPI Institute\\CPR\\Debugging\\cities.txt");

        for (int counter = 4; counter < 5; counter++)
        {
            cboCity.Items.Add(tr.ReadLine());
            cboCity.Items.Add(tr.ReadLine());
            cboCity.Items.Add(tr.ReadLine());
            cboCity.Items.Add(tr.ReadLine());

            tr.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error opening cities file", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Items.AddRange, but before that, you must finish read your file.

Comment: What format your "cities.txt" uses?

Comment: Your `for`-loop is only executed once, you can safely remove it. Alternatively, set `int counter = 0`, remove the multiple calls to `ReadLine()` and take `Close()` to the outside of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
cboCity.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Alexander\\Desktop\\CPI Institute\\CPR\\Debugging\\cities.txt"));
```

to do that in one line.

Answer (score 1):

everytime you call ReadLine method, it will proceed to next line, so the purpose of your loop is gone.

Do something like this,

```
string line;
StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Alexander\\Desktop\\CPI Institute\\CPR\\Debugging\\cities.txt");

while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   cboCity.Items.Add(line);
}

file.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Items.AddRange()`:

```
cboCity.Items.AddRange(new string[] { tr.ReadLine(), tr.ReadLine(), tr.ReadLine(), tr.ReadLine() });
```